# Grass 7 no longer works via the Processing Toolbox on Ubuntu

Tags: qgis, grass-gis, installation, ubuntu, qgis-processing

When I try to execute a Grass 7 algorithm via the Processing Toolbox in QGIS 2.10, 2.8.2 or 2.8.1, I get the following error:

> Missing dependency. This algorithm cannot be run :-(

QGIS erroneously claims Grass 7 is not installed, but it was working fine a few months ago. I'm on Ubuntu 14.04.

I installed Grass 7.0.0-1~exp2~trusty3 on my desktop and laptop using the [UbuntuGIS Unstable PPA](https://launchpad.net/~ubuntugis/+archive/ubuntu/ubuntugis-unstable?field.series_filter=trusty). I installed QGIS 2.10.0 (desktop) and 2.8.2 (laptop) using the software repositories published on the QGIS website.

In an effort to track down the problem, I downgraded my laptop from QGIS 2.8.2 to 2.8.1 using the UbuntuGIS Unstable PPA; the same PPA that provides Grass 7. However, I still get the same error. So I suspect problem is with Grass 7.0.0-1~exp2~trusty3 that was compiled at the end of March.

For a time a few months ago I had Grass 6 and 7 installed along side each other, I was able to access both via Processing in QGIS. Grass 6 is no longer available in the UbuntuGIS Unstable PPA, so downgrading Grass 7 may be impossible.

Does anyone have a fix for this or are you experiencing the same problem?

Comment: same problem here, but no solution so far. Could you maybe post the complete set of repositories you used to install QGIS?

Comment: Indeed, that error message is rather unhelpful since we don't know what the program tried...

Answer (score 4):

The problem has a few days ago been solved in QGIS master. I have prepared a patch for QGIS 2.10 but I hope that the QGIS developers will backport it. Since only Python changes are involved, an existing installation can now be easily fixed without having to reinstall everything.

Comment: I'm seeing this issue on a freshly installed 2.10.1 (ubuntu 14.04) from the qgis debian repos. Has this been fixed alredy or there is something wrong on my side?

Comment: To my knowledge you need to wait for a more recent version.

Comment: For the record: when you now update the Python plugins, you'll receive a working "Processing"...

Comment: I tried updating the Python plugins and still got the same message. Then I completely removed Qgis and grass and reinstalled from the Qgis repos, now I have a working Processing but no grass algorithms!

Comment: You need to reactivate it in the lower right corner and change "Simple" to "Advanced interface" (I suppose)

Comment: Yes, I noticed that but still the same issue. Somehow my Qgis installation got corrupted. I'll try a fresh install.

Comment: Be sure to also move away/remove $HOME/.qgis2/

Comment: Well I've done it all. Purged Qgis and grass (also removed $HOME/.qgis2/), reinstalled both and still no luck! I'm seeing some odd messages in the processing log. I guess I'll open a new question

Comment: Sorry about this. Hope the QGIS folks will help you.