# QGIS 2.10.1 GRASS Processing algorithms not working

Tags: qgis, grass-gis, qgis-plugins, qgis-processing

I just did a fresh install of QGIS 2.10.1 from the qgis repos (Ubuntu 14.04). I also have grass70 installed (through ubuntugis-unstable).

I can see the GRASS7 commands in the processing toolbox panel, but when I try to use them I got the **Missing dependency. This algorithm cannot be run :-(** message.

In the plugins log I noticed that QGIS could not load `libgrassplugin6.so`, but I'm guessing that is not the issue since I'm trying to run grass7 algorithms.

Also, on the processing log I got this output when trying to run a grass 7 command:

```
GRASS GIS 7 execution commands
        g.proj -c proj4="+proj=utm +zone=30 +ellps=intl +towgs84=-87,-98,-121,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs"
        v.in.ogr min_area=0.0001 snap=-1 input="/usr/share/qgis/python/plugins/processing/tests/data" layer=points output=tmp1444494282425 --overwrite -o
        g.region -a n=4458983.8488 s=4458921.97814 e=270855.745301 w=270778.60198 res=100
        v.voronoi input=tmp1444494282425 output=output22e863becb734ae4a06720411090abf0 --overwrite
        v.out.ogr -s -e input=output22e863becb734ae4a06720411090abf0 type=auto output="/tmp/processing/b5eb2443ef0840239dc22209a29a71db" format=ESRI_Shapefile olayer=output
```

But when I try to run a GRASS command (without version, I think that means grass 6, doesn't it?), I got no output on the log. I think that must mean something.

I started QGIS from a console and got this error when I try to execute a GRASS 7 algorithm:

```
ERROR 4: Unable to open /usr/share/qgis/python/plugins/processing/tests/data/points.shp or /usr/share/qgis/python/plugins/processing/tests/data/points.SHP.
```

At first I thought it was a permissions issue (the file exists), so i chmod it to 777 but the error persisted.

Browsing around the processing plugin code, it seems that every time you run a grass algorithm the plugin runs a test using that file.

Comment: If you go in the Processing option, you should find the Provider menu. Be sure to activate only the commands of GRASS 7 and deselect those of GRASS 6.

Comment: Yes, I had those deselected

Answer (score 1):

You need to update the Python plugins. This will include an update to "Processing" as well. It was shipped buggy in 2.10 and got recently fixed and propagated as update.

This will solve the "Missing dependency. This algorithm cannot be run :-(" message.

Comment: I know that markusN, we talked about it in [this](http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/159377/35047) thread. I don't think that's the issue, I did a fresh 2.10.1 install and there's no update to processing plugin

Comment: I hope the QGIS folk can help you...